# Vector space generated by set intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Again, I've come across a simple task, but being new to linear algebra, I wish not yet to question my textbook's author credibility.
In vector space $R^4$ , two subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ are generated by $B_{W_1} = \{ (1,1,0,0), (2,0,-1,0) \}$ and $B_{W_2}=\{ (1,1,1,0),(1,-2,0,1)\}$. Find the dimension of vector space $W_1 \cap W_2$.

My attempts.

First, it is necessary to state that the intersection of an arbitrary numbers of vector subspaces of a vector space $V$ is also a vector space. 
Second, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are respectively given by :
$$W_1 = L(\{ (1,1,0,0), (2,0,-1,0) \})$$
$$W_2 = L(\{ (1,1,1,0),(1,-2,0,1)\})$$
where $L$ denotes the linear span. Then, by using linear combinations,we have the following equation:
$$ \alpha(1,1,0,0) + \beta(2,0,-1,0)  = \gamma (1,1,1,0)+ \delta(1,-2,0,1)$$
This is equivalent to the following system. 
$$\alpha +2 \beta -\gamma -\delta = 0$$
$$\alpha - \gamma +2 \delta = 0$$
$$-\beta -\gamma = 0$$
$$\delta = 0$$

Now, it is obvious that this system has no real solutions, so therefore , 
$$W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$$
where $0$ denotes the zero vector.
This gives us:
$$dim (W_1 \cap W_2) = 0$$ i.e. it is a trivial subspace.
However, the problem arises in the fact that  the solution to this task according to the textbook is $(-1,1,1,0)$ i.e. vector space $W_1 \cap W_2$ is generated by this vector. How is this possible? Am i making a mistake? 
Thank you.

Comment: "Now, it is obvious that this system has no real solutions". This is wrong as $(-1,1,1,0)$ solves the given equations.

Comment: @Stefan I really should stop making such stupid mistakes. The worst thing is, i checked the system solution few times. Interestingly, Wolfram alpha does not generate this solution as a possibility either.

Comment: @Stefan How so?

Comment: @Hagen Oops, I must have flipped a sign.

Comment: @Stefan You seem not to be the only one, as either the textbook author or the OP did so, too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector $(-1,1,1,0)$ does not belong to $W_2$. Indeed,
$$(-1,1,1,0) = \alpha (1,1,1,0) + \beta(1,-2,0,1) $$
implies $\beta = 0$ but then there is not $\alpha$ such that 
$$(-1,1,1,0) = \alpha (1,1,1,0) $$